# autosave programmatically only works here and there

Tags: swift, cocoa

despite no change to my application

programmatically trigering autosave for the window's frame and content size only works usualy once,

I tried differant combination like moving the window around and then cloisng it manualy and yet I still get the same result

I then have to make a new autosave name and then sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't here's my code

```
    view.window?.contentMinSize = NSSize(width: 310, height: 180) //Sets the view window minimum size.
    view.window?.setContentSize(NSSize(width: 510, height: 233)) //Sets the view window normal size.
    view.window?.isRestorable = true
    view.window?.setFrameUsingName(NSWindow.FrameAutosaveName(rawValue: "autosaveformyapp"))
    view.window?.titleVisibility = .visible
    view.window?.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
    view.window?.hasShadow = true
    view.window?.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    view.window?.initialFirstResponder = view
```

update:
I also tried to place the auto save line at differant place
like before setting the window size but same result of it only working 1 time and then not working anymore

Comment: Method `setFrameUsingName`: "Sets the window’s frame rectangle by reading the rectangle data stored under a given name from the defaults system.". Property `frameAutosaveName`: "The name used to automatically save the window’s frame rectangle data in the defaults system.". Do you set this property?

Comment: in my xcode project i set the autosave field to blank(nothing in it)                       because i want to handle it all programaticly if possible

Comment: That isn't autosave. Do you save the frame?

Comment: ok i was able just now to make it work with view.window?.windowController?.windowFrameAutosaveName = NSWindow.FrameAutosaveName(rawValue: "autosaveformyapp") but thats only for the frame what if i want to save the content size?

Comment: just checking agian, and im runing into the same problem it saves the window 2-3 times and then stops working alltogether and wont work even with a new save name

Comment: Related question: [NSWindowController Autosave using Storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150223/nswindowcontroller-autosave-using-storyboard)